# Knockout.js: Getting computed observable to return array for use with select options

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, observable, computed-observable

Basically, what I am trying to achieve is to populate a dropdown based on the value of another dropdown in Knockout.js

My view code(stripped obviously):

```
            <div data-bind="with: chosenMailData">
                <table id="tabl-1234" class="mails">
                    <thead><tr><th>Destination</th><th>Hotel</th></tr></thead>
                    <tbody data-bind="template: { name: 'iti-template', foreach: objects, afterRender: $root.myPostProcessingLogic }">
                </table>
            </div>

            <script type="text/html" id="iti-template">
                <tr>
                    <td><select class="desti" data-bind="options: $root.destinations, value: destination.name"></select></td>   
                    <td><select data-bind="options: $root.generall(), value: $root.generall()"></select></td>
                </tr>
            </script>
```

My View-Model(again stripped-down):

```
            self.destinations=['Kerela', 'Shoghi, Himachal Pradesh', 'Kasauli, Himachal Pradesh'];

            self.myPostProcessingLogic = function(elements) {
                this.generall = ko.computed(function() {
                    $('.desti').each(function(i, obj) {
                        stayOptions = [];
                            $.getJSON("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/hotel?format=json&location__name="+obj.value, function(data) {
                                    $.each(data.objects, function(i, item){
                                    stayOptions.push(item.name);
                                    });
                                });
                    });
                    return stayOptions;
                }, this);
            }
```

Inserting `alert()` in `this.generall()` shows that `stayOptions` does get populated with the values I want in it. It is getting that array to get displayed in select options for corresponding row in Hotels column which is the problem.

Probably I am making a really dumb mistake but I have been looking at the code for a long time now and nothing comes to mind. Please advise.

**EDIT**: I am doing this too at the beginning of my view-model:

```
            self.generall = ko.observableArray();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling methods, the `this` variable gets assigned on invocation.

```
var f = $root.myPostProcessingLogic;
f(); // this will not set 'this' to '$root'
```

The above is essentially what knockout is doing, and this makes `this` be bound to something else inside `myPostProcessingLogic()`. You have already defined the scoped `self` variable, so this is easy to fix.

Another problem is that, reassigning observables won't preserve any subscribers, and any dependant observables won't update.

```
self.generall = ko.observableArray();
self.myPostProcessingLogic = function(elements) {
    self.generall.removeAll();
    $('.desti').each(function(i, obj) {
        $.getJSON("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/hotel?format=json&location__name="+obj.value, function(data) {
            $.each(data.objects, function(i, item){
                self.generall.push(item.name);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for your amazing and quick answer. I am sort of new with Knockout(used Backbone previously) and need help sometimes to find my way around things. Hopefully, one day, I will be as good as you are in coding and debugging. Thanks once again :)